# One ReentrantReadWriteLock instance per Variable to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantreadwritelock

I am going to parallelize some code with some global variables.
I am going to use ReentrantReadWriteLock.
Did I understand it right, that I need one own instance of ReentrantReadWriteLock per variable I want to make thread safe?

I mean, when I have two lists where every thread can attach an item and all threads are sometimes reading items from that lists.
In that case I would implement something like:

```
private static String[] globalVariables = null;
private static String[] processedItems = null;

private final ReentrantReadWriteLock globalVariablesLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock globalVariablesEeadLock  = globalVariablesLock .readLock();
private final Lock globalVariablesWriteLock = globalVariablesLock .writeLock();
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock processedItemsLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock processedItemsLockReadLock  = processedItemsLock .readLock();
private final Lock processedItemsLockWriteLock = processedItemsLock .writeLock();
```

What if I have much more variables like databaseconnection(pool)s, loggers, further lists, etc.

Do I need to make a new ReentrantReadWriteLock or do I missing something?
Samples on the internet only handles one variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add language tags when you make a question. Not everyone comes from the Java world here.

Comment: oh sry forgot it, thanks for doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should have one `Lock` per thread-safe variable (arrays in your case). However, consider using

```
ArrayList<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

instead of arrays. It is usually way better when you delegate to the library (in this case, not only the synchronization but also the resize of the arrays). Of course, before doing it check that the library does exactly what you would expect (in this case, as @SashaSalauyou pointed out, you'd lose the ability to read concurrently).

Comment: The main purpose of `ReadWriteLock` is to allow perform read operations concurrently, which is more effective than serializing read operations as well as write operations. With `synchronizedList` you lose this feature.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou hey I didn't think about that! Thanks!

Comment: thanks for giving a direct answer to my originally question

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to protect?

Don't think of locking *variables*.  The purpose of a lock is to protect an *invariant*.  An invariant is some assertion that you can make about the *state* of your program that must always be true.  An example might be, "the sum of variables A, B, and C will always be zero."

In that case, it doesn't do you any good to have separate locks for A, B, and C.  You want *one* lock that protects that particular invariant.  Any thread that wants to change A, B, or C must lock that lock, and any thread that depends on their sum being zero must lock that same lock.

Often it is not possible for a thread to make progress without *temporarily* breaking some invariant.  E.g.,

```
A += 1;    //breaks the invariant
B -= 1;    //fixes it again.
```

Without synchronization, some other thread could examine A, B, and C in-between those two statements, and find the invariant broken.

With synchronization:

```
private final Object zeroSumLock = new Object();

void bumpA() {
    synchronized(zeroSumLock) {
        A += 1;
        B -= 1;
    }
}

boolean verifySum() {
    synchronized(zeroSumLock) {
        return (A+B+C) == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: One use is a list of pre compiled sql statements where the lists is used as cache. The list is implemented as an projectspecific object, so its not just a hasmap which I could turn into a concurrent equivalent.

The threads shall access this list, take a specific sql, prepare it, set some variables on it and run it on db.
Also some threads access it and dont find the sql they need. So they compile it (from another project specific, sql like language) on runtime and add it to the cache. For this purpose I think reentrantreadwritelock is a good technique.

There are some more objects like this.

Comment: @Kaspatoo what you just described is definitely invariant: by lock you're trying to presreve data integrity, so no thread could see the list in state when items have patially filled properties and so on.

Comment: @Kaspatoo if you're creating your own cache classes, why don't you encapsulate locks in those classes? Common practice for such tasks is to compose API with methods that are executed atomically from caller's point of view (e. g. `ConcurrentMap#putIfAbsent()`), keeping locking mechanism strongly encapsulated.

Comment: I am not able to change those classes because I am not the owner of them and they are not going to change them since they would need to change any existing interface-agreement with other teams

Comment: soo your answer to my question is to use a getter to my objects and synchronize it

but the advantage of using reentrantreadwritelock is that concurrent reads are possible but only one write
thats why I am not going to synchronize

Comment: @Kaspatoo "locking mechanizm" which I'm talking about may be any, not necessarily using synchronized blocks or methods. I'm talking about encapsulation, otherwise you'll need to store that bunch of locks somewhere in your code. The very big problem with this is that your team's code, which also can use those cache objects, may have no idea about synchronization you implemented, or may use their own, which will lead to breaking data integrity. If you're using common contract, define synchronization policy there, otherwise you'll come with poorly designed and erroneous product.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is creating an immutable `Map`, where you put locks for all items you need:

```
final static Map<String, ReadWriteLock> locks = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
     new HashMap<String, ReadWriteLock>() {{
         put("globalVariables", new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
         put("processedItems",  new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
         // rest items
     }}
);
```

As HashMap is wrapped by `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` and thus cannot be modified, it becomes thread-safe.

Then, in code:

```
Lock lo = locks.get("globalVariables").readLock();
lo.acquire();
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
} finally {
    lo.release();
}
```

Comment: I dont think that this would reduce anything, and additionally I would need to make constants not to have hard coded text to get the right lock

my question was more intendet to ask whether I really would need to make an own lock or if I missunderstood the concept